# parse json url in react and get the value of an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After fetching a json file, I would like to read only the value of one element. Here I would like to get the title of the first movie.

```
title   "The Basics - Networking"
description "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!"
movies  
0   
id  "1"
title   "Star Wars"
releaseYear "1977"
1   
id  "2"
title   "Back to the Future"
releaseYear "1985"
2   
id  "3"
title   "The Matrix"
releaseYear "1999"
3   
id  "4"
title   "Inception"
releaseYear "2010"
4   
id  "5"
title   "Interstellar"
releaseYear "2014"
```

Is it possible to get this value directly from the address? For example something like this:

```
 https://reactnative.dev/movies.json=id:1&title?
```

and store it?

Comment: should be `jsonData.movies[0].title` I think

Comment: @WebbH thank you. Sorry for silly question I am new to it.